# Displaying an exception in more browser tabs using Primefaces

Tags: jsp, exception, primefaces

Having a JSF (Primefaces) application we could face exceptions. When such an exception occures in one session in one browser tab, is it possible to display that exception in tab what belongs to the same session?

SK

Comment: Why would you want this? Confusing to the end-user and more. Handle them correctly and show the message...

Comment: The errors are handled correctly. But they still want to have displayed on all opened tabs.

Comment: Ahhhh Now it becomes clear... You gave the impression that you'd want to aggregate all errors on a single browser tab... Generalize your problem... In this case 'exceptions' are most likely just messages. So effectively you want to display a message on multiple tabs... Then use primefaces push